# Smart glasses that allow you to access the video feed in your own code

Tags: ip-camera

A few companies are offering glasses with built in cameras that can record or stream video to an app or to social media. Ray-Ban Meta is a notable example. I'd like to use one to stream to my own code (probably OpenCV, but that is not really important) but my experience with other IP cameras is that you cannot always access the video feed (or you can't discover the URL, username and password for it). I've looked on https://www.ispyconnect.com/cameras but it is not possible to know which cameras are built into glasses (if any).

Have you successfully taken a video feed from smart glasses? If so, what glasses did you use and how did you find the IP feed details?
Thanks!

Comment: Those Ray-Ban Meta glasses are not an IP camera at all. They use a proprietary protocol to talk to an app on your phone over WiFi or Bluetooth, which cannot be hijacked easily to get the individual video frames. Avoid "smart" glasses because they're all locked down to a specific app like this. I doubt that there are any consumer-facing products that don't work this way; You will probably have to DIY something with a tiny camera and tiny computing platform attached to some glasses.